# Mongoose stopped populating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

As title says Mongoose stopped populating post's comments. It works with author, and it worked yesterday. I didn't change anything with get post route. Really confusing, does populate method has kind of limit that can cause this because comment array has a lot of object ids although there are no comments in comment collection.

Here is get post route:

```
    router.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    Post.findById({ _id: req.params.id })
        .populate('author')
        .populate({
            path: 'comments', populate: {
                path: 'author'
            }
        })
        .exec((err, post) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            else {
                res.json(post);
            }
        });
});
```

And also, there are still old comments, but new ones are not there although they are saved in comment collection.

EDIT: Post schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = require('./user');
const Comment = require('./comment');

postSchema = new schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    postImageUrl: String,
    comments: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
})

const Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('post', postSchema, 'posts');
```

And comment schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = require('./user');

commentSchema = new schema({
    comment: String,
    author: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
})

const Comment = module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

Here is comment create route:

```
    router.post('/posts/:id/comments', passport.authenticate('jwt'), (req, res) => {
    var newComment = new Comment({
        comment: req.body.comment,
        author: req.user._id
    });
    newComment.save((err, comment) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Error' + err });
        } else {
            res.json({ success: true, message: 'Success', comment });
        }
    });
});
```

SOLVED: I should unshift or push created comment in post comments array..

Comment: can you post the schema for `Post` and `Comment`?

Comment: please edit the question and post the schema in question

Comment: I have tested in my local, it works fine, can you share the scenario/dataset where it exactly fails to populate?

Comment: When I create new comment, I receive data.success message, then I reload a post detail route, and there is no comment. Here are photos: https://i.imgur.com/PrQ0hb4.png - new comment, https://i.imgur.com/HFIh8Di.png - no comment in array, there was one comment already..

Comment: how are you saving comments? using any cascade strategy? can you post the code for saving posts, users and comments?

Comment: Can you verify it's saving the comment in the database before doing the read?

Comment: @jcragun You mean does it save the comment ? Yes, there is comment in comments collection..

Comment: I see 2 comments in both screenshots, are you rendering to UI properly?

Comment: Comment that is shown on first screenshot is 'new comment' route response, and I tried to render it without reloading the page..On the other screenshot there are no 2 comments as you see in post object..

Comment: I solved it, post edited, thank you for the effort.